# Why do I have linker errors after renaming the function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, linker-errors

Visual Studio 2012. I had a function `CreateMyModulePath` and I renamed it to `CreateModulePath` -- I did it both in .h and .cpp file. I rebuild entire project but VS gives me linker error that it cannot find `CreateModulePath`.

I am completely out of ideas what is wrong -- after all it is pretty basic refactoring, change the function name (declaration + implementation and all the calls). The message says:

> 1>CustomDialog.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __cdecl ih_helpers::CreateModulePath(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &)" (?CreateModulePath@ih_helpers@@YA?AV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@ABV23@@Z)

The CustomDialog is part of this project, and the function `CreateModulePath` is used only in this project. There is no other `CreateModulePath` in entire solution, and besides I always add appropriate namespace prefix.

Comment: Maybe you should copy your code of `CreateModulePath()` here.

Comment: fastest way to solve this is just to rename it back to CreateMyModulePath :D

Comment: Constructing a testcase will solve this for you in five minutes flat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `CreateModulePath()` are the same both in `.h/.cpp`. They should be the same means they must share

- same function name
- same return type
- same input parameter types

Comment: Aahh, C++ refactoring is not that trivial as in C#. Thank you for that reminder, next time I will simply copy&paste declaration to .cpp file.

Comment: @greenoldman Yes, C++ refactoring is not so dependable sometimes.

Comment: @greenoldman You could have a look at VisualAssistX plugin to visual studio. It's not free, but it has some trial period. It has a lot of nice features like automatic renaming and changing signatures, where it will do it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You either missed a couple of references or you failed to rebuild the project completely.